# Roaming Profiles - Win 7 & SBS 2011

Tags: roaming-profile

I have a client network that has all Windows 7 computers (brand new), and a SBS 2011 with roaming profiles setup.

I have created and tested the roaming profiles successfully - so no problem there.

The issue I am having is that some users have already signed onto their PC's, and when I try to use roaming profiles on those PC's, it defaults to the local copy of their profile.

I have tried deleting the local profile, and signing on as them, but it just comes up using the temporary profile... strange..

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How'd you delete the profile? I'm betting that you just deleted the folder from C:\Users. This is the wrong way to delete a profile. Profiles should be deleted using the profile management tool that comes with Windows. In order to fix the problem that you've created, follow the steps in this KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947242